# undefined variable when checking user input with if

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a number [n>2]: "))
        if num <= 2:
            raise ValueError
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number. Try again!")
        continue
```

Is it normal that VSCode is giving me an "undefined variable" on `num` after asking for user input? I mean, `num` will be defined when the user enters a number.

Comment: Have you tried running it? If there is no problem, then you can ignore that warning.

Comment: Also, VS Code is not giving me any warnings.

Comment: Yes, it works no problem. But i wanted to understand why the yellow underline. I've always been taught to solve them

Comment: Yeah sometimes VS Code gives you some false warnings. For example, if there was an error with the code and I change the code but dont save it, the error line remains there until saved.

Comment: Could the problem be that I'm inside of a class?

Comment: @khelwood the loop never breaks...

Comment: @Tomerikoo So it doesn't. The break statement is unreachable. Weird code.

Comment: i made an error when indenting on StackOverflow. break should be outside of the if statement

Comment: Seems to be a vscode bug: https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1908.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to reflect your actual code

Comment: Yeah, of course. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because the VS code debug AI is warning you if you use the num variable in the except block, or somewhere else in the code, it will cause an error. To solve it, you can do this

```
   num = 0
   while True:
       try:
           num = int(input("Enter a number [n>2]: "))
           if num <= 2:
               raise ValueError
               break
       except ValueError:
           print("Not a number. Try again!")
           continue
```

And it should go away since I have defined the variable num to work in all scenarios

Comment: Wouldn't it warn you if you actually used it inside the `except`?

Comment: It should directly give an error if you do that. Warnings say that this could cause a problem. They do not say that the particular line IS causing a problem.  The debug algo can be prone to error and may not be able consider all scenarios so they give the warning just in case